# Podman: slow http requests inside container

Tags: docker-compose, podman, podman-compose

I have a problem to make request from container. It's too slow to google.com.

I use podman version 4.2 and after I up my containers (I use podman-compose) I goes into container and try to make http request.

I worked around and find that in /etc/resolv.conf there is an podman IP which configures all containers. If I remove it - everythinig works okey. But I can't because in this case there is no connection between containers - they don't see each other.

Can somebody helps with it?

I didn't try with podman pods, I believe this can be configured by podman-compose. But I tried many different cases - no one helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: What networking mode do you use?

Comment: I use a standard network bridge.